# jQuery fullCalendar deleting old events on document.ready

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, fullcalendar

I am trying to delete events from my database that are older than 30 days. I don't want to use [removeEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/removeEvents) since that only removes the rendering of the event and not from the database. Or am I wrong about that?

And since there's no deleteEvents function in fullCalendar, I can't call upon my events in the calendar like so: *example:* `event.start.format()` to find out the event's starting date in order to calculate if it's older than 30 days to delete it.

I tried to make a custom function and add it to fullCalendar like so:

```
//-------------- DELETE EVENTS OUDER DAN 30 DAGEN--------------
    deleteEvents: function(event, start, end){
        var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
        var startDate = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        var diff = newDate(Date.parse(start) - Date.parse(currentDate)); //start - current returns difference in milliseconds
        var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24; //get days
        if (days => 30) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "@Url.Action("Delete","medewerker_melding")", //send to Action, Controller
                ajaxasync: true,
                data: {
                    id: event.id, //ID of event that needs to be deleted
                    __RequestVerificationToken: token //ValidateAntiForgeryToken
                },
                success: function () {
                    // redirect
                    window.location.replace('@Url.Action("Index", "medewerker_melding")');
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Fout: verouderde events niet kunnen verwijderen.\nError: " + data);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

but the fullCalendar simply ignores that because it doesn't exist within jQuery fullCalendar. I realize that this script would've never worked anyway but thats besides the point.

So I was hoping that somebody with more experience with jQuery fullCalendar and jQuery itself knows a way to delete events that are older than 30 days from the database on `$(document).ready`.

Thank you.

Comment: why are you trying to do this in the client-side? Surely your server should have an automatic job which runs frequently (e.g. once per day) to remove events older than 30 days from the database directly

Comment: If you really have to trigger this from the browser, just make an Action method in your MVC called "deleteOldEvents" and let that work out which events are older than 30 days in the database, and delete them. Probably with a SQL query it's very easy.

Comment: One last point - finding events older than 30 days within the fullCalendar is never likely to work because the "month" view is usually the biggest period of time displayed (unless you made some custom list view for a whole year or something) so fetching the events currently displayed on the calendar in the browser would be unlikely to discover anything more than 30 days old anyway

Comment: "since there's no deleteEvents function in fullCalendar"..."removeEvents" is the delete function, but yes it only removes events from the calendar itself. Remember that fullCalendar can work quite happily without any kind of server-side or remote data source, it is a completely client-side browser-based tool. If there is interaction with the server, then you have to make the server side code yourself, and, apart from the built-in functionality for reading an "events" JSON feed, any other ajax calls you want to make to the server you have to code yourself and then integrate that to fullCalendar

Comment: alright, I'll try and look for a way to do it server side. Honestly I don't remember why I wanted to do it client side so badly, I was tired and it felt like that was the only way? which is stupid... I realize that fullCalendar has no problem having events old events, the only reason I wanted this is because I didn't want the server end up having 500 rows where only 6 are used and the rest is old data.
also I didn't know you could set something up that would run an sql query e.g. everyday, but I do now ^^.
Thanks for your input, it gave me a new look at things.

Comment: Yep, on Windows you can run a Scheduled Task or create a full-on Windows Service to run on a timer, on Linux you can use cron to run any command on a regular schedule. If you use MS SQL Server you can set a SQL Agent job just to run a SQL query on a schedule, if no other functionality is required. Lots of possibilities depending on your setup.

Comment: yeah I'm working with MS SQL Server. but I don't have the authorization to make a SQL Agent job. so I have to work with procedures. but I can't find a way to make it execute without closing the SQL server manager. it saves on the database but when I try to close the query tab, I get a confirm that if I close it, it will stop executing.

Comment: Then you have to ask your DBA to set up a job which runs the procedure once every day (or however often you wish)

Comment: yeah he said that he doesn't want to do that because they never use an agent job, so I guess it's onto a function in the controller

Comment: well you could potentially create a Windows Scheduled Task either on the webserver or the DB server which runs the procedure via SQL command-line. Again it can be set to run at any interval of time you require.

Comment: As a last resort, you could have something (perhaps via something in global.asax) which runs the procedure every time anyone makes any kind of request to the website, and clears anything up it finds. As long as the procedure only takes a few milliseconds to run it wouldn't affect performance, but it's still "automated" after a fashion

Answer (score 1):

Well after a conversation with @ADyson and a bunch of swearing at my code, I finally solved it

```
public void DeleteOldEvents()
    {

        temphrmEntities db = new temphrmEntities();

        var datecheck = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);

        var q = from n in db.medewerker_melding
                where n.datum_van < datecheck
                group n by n.ID into g
                select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.ID).FirstOrDefault();

        foreach (var ev in q)
        {
            db.medewerker_melding.Remove(ev);
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DeleteOldEvents();
        return View();
    }
```

Thanks @ADyson